# manage ITEM configuration from table APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

Can't find plugin to manage ITEM's rules from table.

For example, i have table - **business_rules (id, item_name, required_condition, readonly_condition, lov_query, lov_type)**

If I write

**id-1, item_name - P23_SURNAME, required_condition - :P23_NAME IS NOT NULL, readonly_condition - YES, lov_query - select 'test' name, '1' id from table, lov_type - POPUPLOV**

Item P23_SURNAME will required when P23_NAME  is not null and LOV must be POPUPLOV with value.

Help, please

Answer (score 1):

Just conditions you might be able to give the item a validation that is plsql code that checks the condition in the table and executes it.

But for changing item type like you want, you will need to dynamically generate all the items with APEX_ITEM inside a PL/SQL Dynamic Content region. Which is not a fun experience, but it can be done.

I did basically the same thing you are trying to do, but I can tell you, it is neither easy nor fun. But it can be done.

GL HF

Comment: I second this. With apex_item, you have little control over the UI and validations are a nightmare.

Comment: @TineO would be grateful if you can reply with resolution on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64903319/why-picklist-not-populating-data-for-custom-dependent-picklist-field-with-lightn

Comment: @CarolynCordeiro Carolyn, it appears that is Salesforce APEX, which is an entirely different thing from oracle-apex which is what this is(despite the two wrong tags, I submitted an edit to remove them). And unfortunately I have no experience with Salesforce APEX so I sadly can not help.